# targeting class in script

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script which (i want it to) adds '.shrink' class to 
quarter-circle class div.

```
<script>
$(function(){

var shrinkHeader = 50;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
  if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
       $('quarter-circle').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('quarter-circle').removeClass('shrink');
    }
 });

function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
});
</script>

<div class="quarter-circle"></div>
```

but It doesn't target it, not sure why.

EDIT- trying to apply this when class is added

css

```
.quarter-circle.shrink {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Where is getCurrentScroll() function? And yes (dot). is missing from quarter-circle

Comment: edited question with source function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) is **.**(dot) not empty character.

So `$('.quarter-circle')` is the answer.

edit:

Your `div.quarter-circle` has no content and width and height aren't specified(so 0x0px size) I made example fiddle for help. check it out.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9k4hk57a/

Comment: @user3550879 can you add full source code? I can't find `getCurrentScroll` function

Comment: edited question with getCurrentScroll function (didn't copy over in original post)

Comment: Perfect! as a side note could I alter it to target 2 objects in the same function. ex. apply a class .shrink2 to .quarter-circle2 when user scrolls aswell?

Comment: @user3550879 just write this `$('.quarter-circle2').addClass('shrink2');` below `$('.quarter-circle').addClass('shrink');` and don't forget to add `removeClass` function too

Answer (score 1):

You should select your element by class using class selector

```
$('.quarter-circle').removeClass('shrink');
```

Here is the  [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<script>
$(function(){

var shrinkHeader = 50;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
  if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
       $('.quarter-circle').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.quarter-circle').removeClass('shrink');
    }
 });
</script>

<div class="quarter-circle"></div>
```

Comment: adding the dot doesn't target it